# Solving $4957^k \equiv 1 \pmod{7007}$ with the chinese remainder theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, chinese-remainder-theorem

Find all natural numbers $k$ that satisfy
$$4957^k \equiv 1 \pmod{7007}$$
where $7007 = 7 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13$.

I know the [chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem), but the $k$ is bugging me?

Comment: And what's the prime factoring of $4957$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** The chinese remainder theorem states that your equation is equivalent to the following system of equations:

$$\begin{align*}
4957^k &\equiv 1 \pmod{49}\\
4957^k &\equiv 1 \pmod{11}\\
4957^k &\equiv 1 \pmod{13}
\end{align*}$$

This is in turn equivalent to
$$\begin{align*}
8^k &\equiv 1 \pmod{49}\\
7^k &\equiv 1 \pmod{11}\\
4^k &\equiv 1 \pmod{13}
\end{align*}$$

Now it's your turn to solve these equations.

**Edit:** The chinese remainder theorem is actually not even necessary to solve this problem. The equivalence between the original equation and the system of equations can easily be deduced without the CRT.

Comment: Euler's theorem implies that $4957^{5040}\equiv1\pmod{7007}$. How is that ($k=5040$) reflected in your answer?

Comment: @barakmanos $k = 5040$ also solves the system of linear equations. But there are also smaller solutions that you don't get just from Euler's theorem. The solutions are precisely the multiples of $210$.

Comment: Yes, I've realized that Euler's theorem is not enough. It just remains a little unclear to me from your answer, how you get to $k$ being a multiple of $5040$ (or even $210$ as you've just mentioned)... Or is that left for the OP to conclude?

Comment: Why does it becomes 210 after you have testing many values when you get mgm(6,7,10)??

Comment: Dominik which other math-techinques can i use instead of CRT?

Comment: @barakmanos I wanted to just give a clue, the rest is for OP to conclude.

Comment: @JonasBo  I don't quite understand your comment. The system is solved iff $7|k$, $6|k$ and $10|k$ is satisfied, which is equivalent to $lcm(6, 7, 10) = 210 | k$. To prove it without the CRT, note that for coprime $a, b$ the equivalence $ab | m \iff a|m $ and $b | m$ holds.